# Image from assets folder not displaying with Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

I have tried looking at different answers here but could not resolve my problem.
I have got a Json server with some data:

```
file.json
    {
      "post": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "title": "Title",
          "description": "Este e um post para saberes mais clica aqui",
          "article": "Hoje este e um novo post etc e tal",
          "photo": "image-1.jpg"
        },
        ]
    }
```

I want my component to render the image on 'photo' in a v-for as I don't want to hard code every time I add a new one. This is what I have in my component.vue:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <h2 class="mt-32 flex justify-center text-3xl ">The Happy Algorithm</h2>
    <div class="grid grid-rows-4 grid-flow-col">
      <div class="ml-12 " v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'post', params: { id: post.id } }">
          <a href=""
            ><img
              class=" mt-8 pt-32 "
              :src="`../assets/${post.photo}`"
              :alt="post.title"
          /></a>
          <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
          <p class="text-justify text-sm pt-6">
            {{ post.description }}
          </p>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import { api } from "@/../services.js";

export default {
  name: "LatestPost",
  props: ["id"],
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getAllPosts() {
      this.posts = [];
      api.get(`/post`).then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data;
        console.log(this.posts);
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getAllPosts();
  },
};
</script>
```

I have tested adding an online image instead of the one I have in my assets and works absolutely fine so I am not sure why doesn't work when I try to load the image from assets.

This is how it displays

[image]

Comment: do you get any errors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this (Path imports)](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports) and [this one(public path)](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports)

If you want to load images dynamically (in your case with the `{{post.photo}}`) you have to move the images to your `/path/to/project/public/` folder. You can build your src-url in the following way then:

```
<img class="mt-8-pt-32" :src="'/' + post.photo" :alt="post.title">
```

When your public path is different, replace the `'/'` with `process.env.BASE_URL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the require function while trying to load the image

```
:src="require(`../assets/${post.photo}`)"
```